# cant connect to jdbc driver mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

While I am trying to connect to mysql database using java class I am getting this error.
Please help I have set the `CLASSPATH: C:\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar`

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
             at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
             at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
             at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
             at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
             at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
             at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
             at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at connect.main(connect.java:17)
Cannot connect to database server
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at connect.main(connect.java:29)
```

Comment: looks like classpath problem. How are you setting it (jar) to classpath?

Comment: by using set CLASSPATH=C:\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar

Comment: Did you check that the jar definitely exists in that location on your system?

Comment: Yes. its in that location only i copy the path an paste it here

Comment: did you try using java -cp "...." your_program_name ?

Answer (score 2):

Add the driver to the classpath:

```
java -cp .;C:\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar connect
```

Comment: @theSound The path needs to point at the location of the jar on *your* system, have you checked that?

Comment: The default jar file is called: mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar, are you sure there is no `bin` in the filename?

Comment: You can also look into the mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar and check that it really contains the Driver class.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting that error, your classpath is not correct. Either you are not including it properly to the java process (`java -cp <classpath> YourClass`) or the mysql connector jar is not located where you are pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `CLASSPATH` environment variable and test your code as suggested by `@morja` and `@pap`. In case you want to set environment variable `CLASSPATH`, then the value of CLASSPATH must be: (Please verify the location of .jar or for the sake of simplicity shorten the folder and .jar file e.g c:\driver\mysqldriver.jar)

```
.;C:\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar
```